# Relationship Between Bayesian Optimization and Gaussian Process

Tags: statistics, optimization, normal-distribution, machine-learning

In [Bayesian Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_optimization#:%7E:text=Bayesian%20optimization%20is%20a%20sequential,expensive%2Dto%2Devaluate%20functions.), the function (i.e. objective function) that we are trying to optimize is modelled using some surrogate function - this surrogate function usually turns out to be a Gaussian Process.

I am trying to better understand - **in Bayesian Optimization, why exactly do we decide to model the objective function using a Gaussian Process?** Could we have based the surrogate on some other class of functions instead?

My guess is that perhaps Gaussian Processes have a certain type of "mathematical flexibility" which makes them an ideal choice for a surrogate models in the context of optimization. But in the end - **is there some specific reason as to why Gaussian Processes are used in Bayesian Optimization (compared to some other class of surrogate function) ?**

Thanks!

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but fwiw this lecture gives a lot of nice intuition about gaussian processes: https://youtu.be/92-98SYOdlY

Comment: Thank you! I will check this out!

Comment: GPs are nice because the model is simple and well understood. But they aren't scalable enough for large datasets - $O(n^3)$ cost!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gaussian distributions are [maximum entropy distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution) and therefore minimize the amount of prior knowledge that is being put into the assumption. In other words, they are a good choice when modeling a high degree of uncertainty. To my understanding there is nothing beyond that. And yes, it could be theoretically correct to base the surrogate on other functions, provided that those functions fit some notion of prior knowledge.

There is a little bit of information about this in Goodfellow's *Deep Learning*.

**EDIT**: There are many kinds of probability distributions. Depending on the context, you will model an experiment (or some data) with a discrete model (a coin toss, for example), a continuous model (if you are evaluating weight, for example) or some more general [probability measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_measure). (If curious about probability measures, the first chapters in Jun Shao's *Mathematical Statistics* are a good choice of study.)

$A)$ We define the self-information of an event $\text{x}=x$ as $I(x)=-\log P(x)$. This is a formalization of the general notion that an event is more informative if it is unlikely, and its information tends to $0$ as its probability tends to $1$.

Generally speaking, we could measure the amount of uncertainty in an entire distribution $p(x)$ with the expected self-information of its elements:

$$H(X)=\mathbb{E}_{x\sim p}[I(x)] = -\mathbb{E}_{x\sim p}[\log P(x)] = -\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x)\log p(x)$$

This is defined as the **Differential Entropy** of the distribution. Distributions that are nearly deterministic have very low entropy; distributions that are closer to uniform have high entropy.

$B)$ We define a maximum entropy distribution as any distribution whose entropy is as great or greater as that of any other distribution of the same family.

$C)$ There is a theorem whose proof is clearly exposed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy) that states that, given certain variance, a Gaussian random variable has the largest entropy amongst all random variables with equal variance.

$D)$ Lastly, it is a reasonable choice —if you are taking the Bayesian perspective— to pick as your prior whatever distribution has maximum entropy, because it means you are making the least possible amount of assumptions. This can be seen as an application of [Occam's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor), which you may find interesting if more philosophical ideas appeal to you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you please go over maximum entropy a bit more? Thanks!

Comment: I have expanded my answer to suit your request

Comment: Thank you so much for your updated answer!  I have started reading about maximum entropy! Just a question - do you know anything about Bellman Optimality? I posted a question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4447435/can-machine-learning-models-be-considered-as-approximate-dynamic-programming . Do you have any comments about this?

Comment: No problem, I hope my answer was able to clarify at least some of your doubts. If it was helpful, please don't forget to mark the answer. I do not know much about Bellman Optimality but I will revise your other question and see if I can help.

Comment: Thank you! I will check your answer!

Comment: Re gaussian process: my general guess was that gaussian processes might have the innate ability to well-recover the true function based on discrete realizations from this function?

Comment: @ lafinur: your notes on maximum entropy lead to me posting a new question about this topic! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4447849/does-entropy-explain-why-the-normal-distribution-is-so-popular

Comment: @ lafinur: another question i had - are  gaussian processes  less computationally expensive to fit than deep neural networks? My guess is yes, since there usually tends to be a closed form solution?

Comment: @stats_noob Hi. In all honesty, I have no idea, though it is intuitive to think so. On another note, I have provided answers for both of your other questions, please don't forget to mark them as correct if they were helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if the maximal entropy property pointed out in another answer is relevant at all, it is for a different reason than "modeling a high degree of uncertainty" (note that GP is a stochastic process - a probability distribution over functions - such that each value is a 1D Guasian; maximal entropy property of 1D Gaussian have a priori little to do with the choice of the distribution over functions that you make for your model).

The main thing that makes everything work is that **conditioning multivariate Gaussian gives a multivariate Gaussian**.

The reason this is key for BO is that together with Kolmogorov's extension theorem, this means that the class of Gausian processes is closed under Bayesian updating. Now, add the fact that a Gaussian is determined by its mean and covariance on top of that, and you are in business.

The reason that it is at all connected to the maximal entropy property is that properly understood **multivariate** maximal entropy property **implies** the key property "conditioning a multivariate Gaussian gives a multivariate Gaussian". Namely,  maximal entropy distribution conditioned on a collection of expectations is a memeber of [an exponential family of an appropriate kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family#Maximum_entropy_derivation). Adding an observation of one of the components is simply adding another expectation (of a "delta function of the component"), that happens to preserve Gussianness of the corresponding exponential family. (Another explanation of this property can be given via central limit theorem).